# How to remove spacing between lines in UICollectionView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a `UICollectionView` and I can't get 0 spacing between lines. I have added `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in `.h` class and implemented

```
(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section**
```

methods set them to return 0.0. Also in `ViewDidLoad` I dynamically created `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `UICollectionView`. For `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` I set `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` to 0 but space between lines is still more than 0.

This is my code:

```
- (void)initializeCollectionView {

UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 100);
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];

flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

collView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[collView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[collView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

collView.delegate = self;
collView.dataSource = self;

[[self view] addSubview:collView];

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 100;

}



- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

return 0.0;

}


- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

return 0.0;

 }


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you calculate itemSize, sectionInset and minimumLineSpacing?

Comment: Yes, in initializeCollectionView method...

Comment: I didn't see sectionInset?

Comment: Yes I didn't set sectionInset... I set it now flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); but it is still the same.

Comment: Yes, try to set itemSize, sectionInset and minimumLineSpacing. Calculate how to fix items with LineSpacing = 0. `minimumLineSpacing =0` ,minimum means it can be greater than 0. So you have to fix itemSize and sectionInset

Comment: What ever I do it won't work...

Comment: I tried with my codes. When I set minimumLineSpacing=0; -> space=0. Maybe minimumLineSpacing=0; is enough. Let check your cell

Comment: Can you show  `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: Did you to do somethings like reloadData, setCollectionViewLayout? It's weird. When I set minimumLineSpacing=0 in my codes. It becomes space =0, without do anything else.

Comment: No, nothing like that. collView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout]; only here I'm setting flowLayout.

Comment: My code :_flowGrid = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
  _flowGrid.itemSize = CGSizeMake(234, 256);
  _flowGrid.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15);
  _flowGrid.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8;
  _flowGrid.minimumLineSpacing = 20;
  _flowGrid.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
__collectionViewProfiles = [[ProfilesCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:_flowGrid];.    When I set minimumLineSpacing = 0. It works

Comment: I somehow managed to get space between lines 0. But I'm not sure will it be responsive design.

Comment: I didn't use (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section also. Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I can't I need 10 reputation to post images.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a little different way. I created a collectionView programatically and added that to the view Controller. In my CollectionView Custom Class, I did all the customisation.

My Custom Collection View interface file-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface CustomCollectionView : UIView<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

    @property(nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end
```

Now in the implementation File(CustomCollectionView.m), first I had to initialise and add my collectionView.

`initWithFrame` is called as soon as the view is drawn. So, I added my collectionView inside this view and let this view deal with all the delegate methods to customise my collection view and populate data  through datasource methods.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
        self.myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, frame.size.width, frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        self.myCollectionView.delegate=self;
        self.myCollectionView.dataSource=self;

        [self.myCollectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];

        [self addSubview:self.myCollectionView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, let's implememt the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //here I just made sure that I have square spaces boxes as my cell size
    int width = self.myCollectionView.frame.size.width/5;
    int height = width;
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Now the UICollectionView Datasource

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 7;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell){
       //customize the cell here
       return cell;
    }
}
```

Now when my custom view with collectionView is ready, I just added that to my viewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomCollectionView *myCollectionView = [[CustomCollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview: myCollectionView];

}
```

The above worked for me. You can do with storyboard to, but I found some complication when I tried to customise a collectionView connected by IBOutlet. So, I took this approach. There may be better ways to do that.

Comment: I also implemented all programmatically and without IBOutlet. And just like yours. But i fix the problem. I managed to get space 0 between lines. I had to change size of item and minimumInteritemSpacing and some other properties to get that... Thanks for your answer.